# VS codeanalysis CA1062 fires even after null check

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sitecore, fxcop

I have a Sitecore project in which I am using visualstudio code analysis. I am using Sitecore method "Assert.ArgumentNotNull" to check for null arguments, However visualstudio code analysis engine doesn't recognize it and show "CA1062  Validate arguments of public methods" message.

Instead of creating a custom rule, Is there a easier way to tell analysis engine that "Assert.ArgumentNotNull" performs null check and message is invalid.

I don't want to suppress the message or disable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Sitecore's `Assert` class that way and that's why:

Sitecore `Assert` class as well as `NotNullAttribute` and `CanBeNullAttribute` were made the way ReSharper can understand when it performs its own analysis.

Definition of `Assert.ArgumentNotNull(object, string)` method is the following:

```
[AssertionMethod]
public static void ArgumentNotNull([CanBeNull] [AssertionCondition(AssertionConditionType.IS_NOT_NULL)] object argument, [CanBeNull] [InvokerParameterName] string argumentName)
```

All those attributes are defined in Sitecore and R# understands them because of naming conventions.

Unfortunately, VS code analysis has another naming conventions. `ArgumentNotNull` should look like this for you:

```
public static void ArgumentNotNull([ValidatedNotNull] object argument, string argumentName)
```

Since you can't modify the `Assert` class, you can't mark `argument` parameter with `ValidatedNotNullAttribute`.